# How to connect Aws S3 to Wowza Streaming Engine?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, wowza

We have finished our project.we have using  many Web Server in our project and also we have used  AWS S3 server to save the media files.we have run app in web & Android & IOS deceives. That time videos are taking long time to play in  our application. we are planning to use Wowza Streaming Engine for video streaming. But We don't no how to connect the Wowza Streaming Engine to AWS S3 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once You enable a Stream option in AWS particular bucket. After You have use Stream url for  Streaming. No use bucket Url. Fellow this [enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html)

Answer (score 1):

After you've created your S3 bucket, you mount it as a local file system.
If you are using the pre-built AMI provided by Wowza, then you can use the built-in application named **vods3**. This application is already configured to use Media Cache so that after the first playback, the files are cached on the local instance therefore providing better performance for subsequent requests.

Also, if you are recording live streams from Wowza Streaming Engine, there is a **wse-plugin-s3upload** module that you can use to automatically copy the recorded files to a S3 bucket. Available on GitHub, https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-plugin-s3upload

Playback URL would look like this, using an HLS playback as an example with a video name **myStream.mp4** located in your S3 bucket named **mybucket** in a folder named **myvideos**.

```
http://[instance-public-dns]/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazon3:mybucket/myvideos/myStream.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```